# How to pass an HttpContext to a dependency initialization in MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, ninject

I am using Ninject in MVC3 application.

One of my resolvable dependencies makes use of `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data")`

Back when I was initializing an IoC container in Global.asax (Application_Start), I was able to just define in my module configuration:

```
.WithConstructorArgument("basePath", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"));
```

Since my module was being initialized from the same thread as the Application, `HttContext.Current` wasn't null.

Then I had to move my Dependency Injection initialization to an PreAppStart method, using the `WebActivator`. Since the HttContext is not yet available in this scenario, I had to remove the parameter initialization of my dep.

I had worked around the problem by resoling the `HttpContext` inside my class instance at runtime. But it turns out it was possible only as long as the instance was being called from the Request Thread. As soon as I have moved the resolved instance call to a separate thread (not to be halting the Controllers' `ActionResult` generation), I arrived at the same problem - no longer able to get `HttpContext`. How can I resolve it in my scenario?

P.S. Just figured out I still can just call a method on my dependency from Global.asax Application start and feed the `HttpContext` from there. Nevertheless, let me know which is the best way to do it.

Comment: Would HostingEnvironment.MapPath work for you instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a way in Ninject to register the dependency in a lazy way using a delegate. This way it will only resolve it when you access the dependency.

Here is how I do it using StructureMap:

```
For<HttpContextBase>().Use(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

As far as accessing the HttpContext from a different thread, you can use the AsyncManager.Sync(d) method that takes a delegate and runs it in the ASP .NET worker process.